# 20uA 2 terminal current source?

Tags: analog, current-source

Is there a trick to implementing the current source in the setup below, for 20uA ballpark (besides switching or steering a pair of individual source/sink)?
[image: current-source-steered-with-bridge]

This is in a single supply roughly 5V system (3.3V would be nice as a bonus). One of the objectives is to reduce dependence on Vcc.

Other details: signal is 0.1-1kHz. Accuracy goal is 10% over parts and temperature (10-50C machine compartment).

The input to the bridge is rougly R2R, the voltage at the output end is roughly mid supply, so current should flow in both hi/low states.

LM334 was about the only thing I found, and it seems a bit dated and temperature sensitive.

Maybe something clever with an op amp and a voltage reference?

Comment: If output is midrail and input is rail-to-rail then the voltage across the current source is nearly constant. Would a resistor work as a "current source"? 5V - 1.2V = 3.8V across the current source. 3.8V / 10uA = 0.38 MOhm. So you could try 390k 1% resistor. If this works please make it into an answer yourself and accept it rather than leave the question officially unanswered.

Comment: That's what I have now (40-60K 1%, somewhat higher current in existing application), and it does work. I should've said I'm shooting for something that takes away the dependence on Vcc. (updated question to include this). There are some other benefits of a constant current output that I was hoping to get without too much part count.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to have an op-amp/reference current source that operates from < 20uA and settles within microseconds. Steering two current sources seems more sensible and even so the diode capacitance may be a factor.

Comment: I'm not sure how the temperature coefficient will work out, but have you considered the basic JFET current source? You can go to arbitrarily low currents as you adjust the resistance, and it only takes two components. You might have trouble if the voltage is too low, though....

Comment: @Hearth, do you have a specific one in mind? Is it some kind of ratio to I_DSS?

Comment: @PeteW I don't recall the equations, but if you put a resistor between the gate and source of a JFET, and apply a voltage between drain and gate, it'll act as a current source depending on the resistance of the resistor.

Comment: Ok thanks. Vaguely familiar with that one, didn't know it could be reproducible across part variation.

Comment: @PeteW I'm not sure if it is, you may have to tune it. And again, no clue if it's temperature-stable.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest current source I know is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPcAes.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not sure it will work but you can play with it. D1 and D2 are being used to establish a voltage reference (probably around 1V in this case). R1 is being used to limit the current flowing through D1 and D2. That current should be limited to a small fraction of the total desired current, otherwise it won't really behave like a current source at all.

The base of Q1 should be held at a fairly constant voltage regardless of V1, since D1 and D2 are a voltage reference.

Since Q1 is set up as a voltage follower, the voltage at R2 will be Vb - Vbe, again, independent of V1. This means the voltage at R2 will be constant. Which means the emitter current will be constant. Which means the collector current will be pretty much constant also.

I have used this circuit before but not at such low current levels. I have used it to drive LED's from variable voltage sources, and it works great for that purpose. So you can try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: I think I was using 10uA as the desired current source current. You would change R2 to adjust the current. Keep R1 as large as you can get away with based on minimum voltage and minimum beta of the transistor.

Comment: Thanks. That's similar to the LM334 in how it would be applied... That one is 0.3% / C which eats up most of the accuracy I would like. My wish, that I'm not sure if it exists, is something like TLV431, but with the minimum current of the 334 or a circuit like yours. I can make a great sink out of the 431 but not a 2-terminal device.

Comment: Well you could use a voltage regulator. An LDO with low quiescent current, low output voltage, and high PSRR. Maybe the  ISL21080-09. This is a three pin LDO. Worst case Iq is only 1.5uA. Vout is 0.9V. So the input current will be Iq + Iout. If you put a 47k resistor on the output, it will act like a current source. However, it may need some capacitance to work correctly, and that may hurt your application.

Comment: That might do it. Let me look it up ...

Comment: As far as this simple current source goes, it works better than you might think. It may be worth your while to simulate it over temperature. The diodes compensate somewhat for the change in Vbe with temperature.

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the datasheet for the LM334. There is a section in the datasheet dedicated to modifying it so it has zero temperature coefficient. I suspect you can get an LM334 to work perfectly for your application, as long as you don't need high bandwidth.

Comment: "as long as you don't need high bandwidth" ... not really, but that is relative. A flat ish response to 20kHz would probably be needed for the 1kHz max input rate. I realize transistors must slow down at low currents. I haven't personally used the bridge current steering scheme like this. The hope was that seeing a constant voltage pretty much all the time except during the transitions would put less demands on it.

Comment: re: LM334 + diode ... perfect, thanks!!  That's enough info to breadboard it and see what happens.

Comment: Looking at the ISL21080 ... 2V min input voltage (plus the voltage drop in the series resistor) makes it too tight a squeeze. If the output side voltage is 2.5V it won't work with 2 diode drops in the bridge. The simplicity might make it worth raising the output side however.

Comment: Yeah, my intent was not to use a series resistor. Just let the input current be equal to the output current, and ignore the quiescent current. So there would just be a load resistor to set the current. The problem is that unless it can operate without filter capacitors, it may have terrible frequency response. The datasheet gives no indication that it would work without caps. So maybe the LM334 is your best option.

Comment: Don't see any reason against caps in there

Comment: Anyway this might be an overly hard path to take. Was throwing it out there in case someone had a good solution

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days working out a different approach, I returned to this concept, with a regulator and an op amp. Note sure about the speed -- will build it and see!

[image]

The voltage at the bottom of the regulator is 1.25V below the top of R1. The OPA makes the bottom of R1 match this voltage, setting the current. Voltage drop inside the bridge is 1.25V + Vce.

R2 should give the regulator enough current so it can respond relatively fast during the transitions. That is the weakness of the inside-the-bridge concept. When the control signal transitions, the voltage inside the bridge collapses. This is a much worse disturbance for the current source compared to the outside-the-bridge-configuration (discussed elsewhere).

On the other hand, it's an attractively low discrete package count. The diodes are a quad, the transistor and OPA can be part of a pair or quad too, and all the parts can be ones that are already standard in my world.